# Determining OS X version from Time Machine backup

Tags: macos, time-machine, imac

I have Time Machine backups from my iMac Early 2008 (20"). Can I determine from those backups what OS X version was running on the machine at the time of latest backup?

Answer (score 9):

Just open the file

```
/Volumes/BackupVolumeName/BackupName.ext/ComputerName/latest/VolumeName/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist
```

to determine the product version ("latest" is a sym-link).

BackupName.ext, BackupVolumeName, ComputerName and VolumeName are all variable and depend on the type of backup or the names configured/given to your backup volume, Mac and main system volume. BackupName.ext is often *Backups.backupdb* though.

Here is my SystemVersion.plist (it's the original file and not a file in a  backup) opened in PlistEdit Pro. You may also open it with an arbitrary text editor or Xcode:

[image: SystemVersion.plist]

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can look at the value of the **ProductVersion** in the **SystemVersion.plist** file located at, e.g., `/Volumes/Backup/Backups.backupdb/<ComputerName>/yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss/Macintosh HD/System/Library/CoreServices/`.

The **SystemVersion.plist** is an XML plist file so, you can just open it in TextEdit, if you do not have a **.plist** editor and you'll see as an example:

```
<key>ProductVersion</key>
<string>10.8.5</string>
```

Comment: Hmmm.  Unfortunately, in each of my backups, including the latest, there is no `…/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist`though it does exist in the booted system.  On the booted system, in Monterey, the "key" is "ProductUserVisibleVersion"

Comment: @WGroleau, This answer was posted nearly six and a half years ago and was at that time accurate as stated for the then current versions of **OS X**. It is not unusual for **Apple** to change things from one version of **macOS** to another, especially so many years later. I'd suggest using the `find` command with `-type f -regex '.*/SystemVersion.plist'` or `-type f -iname 'SystemVersion.plist'` to try and locate it.

Comment: three copies of `find` (three backup disks) have been running for ten hours without finding such a file, in backups going back to December 2020.  Spot checks of about a dozen backups show that none have such a file in System/Library/CoreServices.  The file name does appear in XCode SDKs but those are for the version the SDK applies to.  There is also a file in "Recovery" in every backup, but ALL of those says "10.15.7"  See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/429790/identifying-macos-versions-in-backups for more detail.

Comment: The mystery is why many files in /System/Library/CoreServices are not in ANY of my backups.  That directory is NOT in my list of exclusions.

Comment: @WGroleau on Big Sur and Monterey, Time Machine no longer backs up the unchanging parts of macOS. So if you were to look in Applications, you'd find a bunch of those missing too. Apple's expectation now is that if you need to restore the whole system, you perform a clean install of macOS, and then run migration assistant from your backup. There is no more backing up and restoring macOS itself. Since SystemVersion.plist is an unchanging part of macOS, it's not backed up. I would also like to know how to check which version of macOS backed up a specific Time Machine, but don't have an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As of Big Sur, the previous solution no longer works, because Time Machine no longer backs up the unchanging parts of macOS, which are stored separately in a Sealed System Volume, which is hidden from you during normal use, but which you can see with Disk Utility.

As a workaround, to see which version of macOS made a particular Time Machine backup, you can boot into Recovery mode (hold down command-R on Intel Mac, hold down power button during startup on Apple silicon Mac), and choose restore from Time Machine backup. You'll get a list of dates and corresponding macOS versions.

You can't actually restore these backups outright (because macOS is no longer backed up in its entirety), but Recovery will still show them to you. To restore from a backup made by Big Sur or later, you need to clean install macOS, then run Migration Assistant.

Answer (score 0):

Since `SystemVersion.plist` is not available in current systems, I wanted an easier method than booting into recovery mode.  For someone less disorganized, that would just be keeping a log of updates.  But for me and folks like me, I created an cron job of

```
~/bin/SysID > ~/Versions/$(sw_vers -productName)_$(sw_vers -productVersion)_$(sw_vers -buildVersion)
```

and the script SysID is

```
date
uname -a
sw_vers -productName
sw_vers -productVersion
sw_vers -buildVersion
df -g | grep -vi backup
```

So now, each backup contains a record of its version and all previous versions, the approximate time of each and the approximate amount of disk space of each.

And `ls -lat ~/Versions` tells me the date of each O.S. update.

Answer (score -1):

Perfect information. One little addition. If you've got a really big monitor (as I do) you can read the SystemVersion.plist file just by clicking it and looking at the "carousel" preview in the Finder window.