# Identifying macOS versions in backups

Tags: macos, ios, backup, time-machine

If I go to ~/Library/Application\ Support/MobileSync in my boot system or in a Time Machine backup, I can look in Backup/*/Manifest.plist to find what versions of iOS were backed up.

**Is there a human-readable way to know what version of macOS was in a particular Time Machine backup (other than restoring it to use "About this Mac")?**

A related question is [Determining OS X version from Time Machine backup](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175515/determining-os-x-version-from-time-machine-backup/175529?noredirect=1#comment614782_175529) but it is six years old, and if the answer was valid then, it is not valid for any of my backups which go back to December 2020.

I have found SystemVersion.plist files in some of the backups, but **all** of them, from December 2020 till today say "10.15.7" and many of the backups have nothing but CoreServices.bundle in that director.  Yesterday, I had 11.something and now I have 12.0.1 which is what is stated in the file in my running system.  So the file in the latest backup is DIFFERENT than the file that Time Machine should have put there!

Update: `find` has been crawling the backups for more than 24 hours and has found some SystemVersion.plist files, but the few I've looked at so far have seemingly contradictory contents.  And some of them cite versions that I know have never been on this machine—bought it with Catalina and immediately put Big Sur on it before any backups.

Comment: This looks like two distinct questions to me. How would iOS backup affect a Time Machine interval of a specific macOS? Or is that an analogy and you just want to know if a similar mechanism exists for determining macOS snap data?

Comment: Command line is “human readable” to me - so I’ll try to answer using that as well as a graphical tool if that’s what you mean by “human readable”

Comment: As the comments here and on the other question _clearly_ state, this question does NOT have an answer there.

Comment: “Human-readable” or easily converted to text.  Not interested in writing a lot of code to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Each interval when TimeMachine backs up files writes a SystemVersion.plist file to document the version running the backup.

- [Determining OS X version from Time Machine backup](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175515/determining-os-x-version-from-time-machine-backup)

  /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist

The above file is what shows you the current version, so you would browse the destination of choice to validate what version was running in the past if you are not interested in the Latest instance that the linked question provides.

For searching TimeMachine data, there is no better tool than BackupLoupe. I would use that to locate the files in question if you can’t use `mdfind` or just enumerate them by date for occasional lookup.

- https://www.soma-zone.com/BackupLoupe/

One tip for backuploupe is if you have a non-empty drive, have it index only a few snaps first and see if it suits your needs before letting it digest a drive overnight.

Comment: Unfortunately, in all of my backups, including the latest, there is no `…/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist`though it does exist in the booted system.  Were it not for that little obstacle, I would have said my question is a duplicate.  Might be worth a separate question why TM is not backing up most of the files in /System/Library.

Comment: When I checked, I had two of my backup disks dismounted.  Upon remounting them and checking again, I found that two of them do have instances of `…/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist`  I have no explanation for why one of them does not.  I also found that each backup volume has a `Backups.backupdb/.RecoverySets` for each major version of macOS.  That contains a DMG which holds an installer for that version and a `*/com.apple.recovery.boot/SystemVersion.plist` for _one_ of the minor versions in that major version.

Comment: One of the backup volumes has a `…/2021-08-01-183203/ISSD/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist` but three `find` processes (one on each backup volume) have been running for 150 minutes without finding any other.  The one from August first is for version 10.15.7.  Current version is 12.0.1

Comment: Yeah - crawling directory on a hard linked time machine destination is an exercise in futility. Does `mdfind` help? You probably need BackupLoupe, though @WGroleau

Comment: mdfind showed nothing.  BackupLoupe might be nice for finding things AFTER it has done the same scanning that `find` has been doing for ten hours.  BackupLoupe spent about twenty seconds "initializing" and then was unable to find such a file.  So far, it seems the answer is "No, there is no way."  Every backup from late 2020 till today has little or nothing in `System/Library/CoreServices` but each one has a Recovery directory that does contain a `SystemVersion.plist`  Unfortunately, ALL of those say "10.15.7" and I am already on 12.0.1

Comment: Oddly, the file I found in the 1 August 2021 backup is no longer there, though its parent CoreServices directory is still there.  WTH?